# Finding empty string when integer is present: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Tags: python, string, csv

I am getting an empty string when my CSV file actually contains an integer. You can see where the errors occur by where they are marked with comments. It is currently printing out 1950 on one line when I ask it to, then when I ask it to convert '1950' to an int, it says it cant convert an empty string to an int.

Please help! I apologize that this is a basic question, I'm fairly new to all this.

Code:

```
import Averages
import csv

def csv_info(filepath):
"""Takes in a CSV file that contains information on the models used 
in the program in later functions. Outputs a dictionary of dictionaries, mapping each model to
its specific information."""

output = {}

for row in csv.DictReader(open(filepath)):
    output[row["Model"]] = row
return output



def rho_calc_interp(model, interp_y_n): 

    model = csv_info("/home/patold/Organized_Files.csv")[model]
    if 'MOHC' in model["Model"]:
        start = '12-'
        end = '11.nc'
    else:
        start = '01-'
        end = '12.nc'
    if 'woa' not in model["Filename"]: # If the data is not WOA data
        print (model["s_yr"]) # Prints 1950
        s_yr = int(model["s_yr"]) # Finds an empty string???
        e_yr = int(model["e_yr"])
        # More...

def tryAll():
    modelInfo = csv_info("/home/patold/Organized_Files.csv")
    models = []
    for i in range(len(modelInfo.keys())):
        models.append(list(modelInfo.keys())[i])
    for model in range(len(models)):
        x1 = Averages.rho_calc_interp(str(models[model]), "No")
    print ("FINAL: ")
    print (x1)

tryAll()
```

output:

```
Program Finished.
1950
/home/patold/.conda/envs/cmip5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/io/netcdf.py:297: RuntimeWarning: Cannot close a netcdf_file opened with mmap=True, when netcdf_variables or arrays referring to its data still exist. All data arrays obtained from such files refer directly to data on disk, and must be copied before the file can be cleanly closed. (See netcdf_file docstring for more information on mmap.)
  ), category=RuntimeWarning)
/home/patold/.conda/envs/cmip5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/ma/core.py:4185: UserWarning: Warning: converting a masked element to nan.
  warnings.warn("Warning: converting a masked element to nan.")
FINAL: 
{'Densities': array([ nan,  nan,  nan, ...,  nan,  nan,  nan]), 'Depths': array([  5.00000000e+00,   1.50000000e+01,   2.50000000e+01, ...,
         5.16612988e+03,   5.49924512e+03,   5.83129443e+03])}

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-27-c1efed0bb6ff>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('/home/patold/Spyder_Py_Files/Driver.py', wdir='/home/patold/Spyder_Py_Files')

  File "/home/patold/.conda/envs/cmip5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 866, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "/home/patold/.conda/envs/cmip5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "/home/patold/Spyder_Py_Files/Driver.py", line 51, in <module>
    tryAll()

  File "/home/patold/Spyder_Py_Files/Driver.py", line 47, in tryAll
    x1 = Averages.rho_calc_interp(str(models[model]), "No")

  File "/home/patold/Spyder_Py_Files/Averages.py", line 183, in rho_calc_interp
    s_yr = int(model["s_yr"])

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

SOLVED:

I went in and deleted what appeared to be blank cells in the CSV file in Excel. Saved this, and it works now. Apparently it was reading in a blank row...

Comment: Please fix your code's indentation.

Comment: Done, sorry about that.

Comment: Your program is printing out `FINAL:` before the error occurs, but there are no calls to `rho_calc_interp` after that is printed; can you explain this?

Comment: Code is still not properly indented.

Comment: You are calling `rho_calc_interp` in a loop. You are seeing the print from a successful call and the exception from a subsequent call. You see nothing printed on the subsequent call because it is printing an empty string.

Comment: Please also include a sample of your csv. Are all rows aligned? Or any extra spaces somewhere?

Comment: @XinHuang The error was indeed in the CSV file. It was properly formatted, but appears that there was a blank cell with a space in it thank was throwing everything off.